# Prove that if $\kappa$ is an uncountable regular cardinal that is also a limit cardinal, then $\kappa = \aleph_{\kappa}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A cardinal $\kappa$ is regular if whenever $X \subseteq \kappa$ with $|X|<\kappa$ then $supX<\kappa$. And a cardinal is a limit cardinal if it is of the form $\aleph_{\beta}$ where $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

So I know that $\kappa=\aleph_{\beta}$ for some limit ordinal $\beta$, and I know that $\kappa\leq\aleph_\kappa$. I'm thinking that the right way to proceed on with this is to assume $\kappa<\aleph_\kappa$ and prove by contradiction.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\kappa&<\aleph_\kappa\\
\kappa = \aleph_\beta&<\aleph_\kappa\\
\beta &< \kappa
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Im not sure how to proceed on from here! More importantly, I don't know how to make use of the fact that $\kappa$ is regular..

Some hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\aleph_\beta=\sup\{\aleph_\alpha:\alpha<\beta\}$.  Now use regularity.

Comment: Alright thanks! Got it!